# Fractional derivative of the Wright function

Tags: special-functions, linear-pde, fractional-calculus

It is mentioned in some papers (Appendix in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.2950v1.pdf), for example) that the (formal) solution of the fractional drift (or transport) equation
$$
\partial_{t}^{\alpha}u(t,x)+\partial_{x}u(t,x)=0\quad\text{and}\quad u(0,x)=f(x)\quad\text{($x\in\mathbb{R}$, $t\ge0$)}
$$
is given as
$$
u(t,x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^{\alpha}}\phi\left(-\alpha,1-\alpha;-\frac{y}{t^{\alpha}}\right)f(x-y)dy.
$$
Here $0<\alpha<1$, $\partial_{t}^{\alpha}$ denotes the fractional differential operator in Caputo sense defined by
$$
\partial_{t}^{\alpha}g(t):=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{g'(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha}}ds=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}\frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{g(s)-g(0)}{(t-x)^{\alpha}}ds
$$
and $\phi$ is the Wright function defined by
$$
\phi(\beta,\gamma;z):=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{k}}{k!\Gamma(\beta k+\gamma)}.
$$

This solution is given by taking the Laplace transform of the equation.

> I would like to ask whether this function is indeed a solution of the fractional drift equation via direct calculations or not.

The problem I'm stacking is just one; I cannot calculate $\partial_{t}^{\alpha}u$.
As you immediately think, I have tried to calculate as follows:
$$
\partial_{t}^{\alpha}u=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-y)^{k}}{k!\Gamma(-\alpha k+1-\alpha)}\partial_{t}^{\alpha}t^{-\alpha(k+1)} f(x-y)dy.
$$
However, $\partial_{t}^{\alpha}t^{-\alpha(k+1)}$ does not converge.
For the reason, I'm finding the other way to calculate but I don't find.

Thank you for advance.

Comment: $\partial_{t}^{\alpha}\frac{t^{-\alpha(k+1)}}{(-\alpha(k+1))!}=\frac{t^{-\alpha(k+2)}}{(-\alpha(k+2))!}$in the usual interpretation of such a fractional derivative.

Comment: Taking the derivative w.r.t. x of the convolution integral, integrating by parts, and comparing to the derivative w.r.t. t should give the desired results.

Comment: @TomCopeland How is the equality derived? I recognize that the (left side) Caputo derivative of negative power functions is undefined...

Comment: The fractional integro-derivatives of the divided powers for $t \ge 0$ are designed to rep the operation  $\partial_{t}^{\alpha}H(t) \frac{t^{-\alpha(k+1)}}{(-\alpha(k+1))!}=H(t)\frac{t^{-\alpha(k+2)}}{(-\alpha(k+2))!}$ where $H(t)\frac{t^{-n-1}}{(-n-1)!}$ for $n \ge 0$ are essentially the Dirac delta function or its $n$'th derivative and $H(t)$ is the Heaviside step function. See any survey paper on fractional derivatives (e.g., links in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/why-is-eulers-gamma-function-the-best-extension-of-the-factorial-function-to/133194#133194).

Comment: Fot $t \gt 0$, dividing by $(-n-1)!$ gives zero for $n$ a positive integer.

Comment: I view the Caputo derivative as an analytic continuation of the Riemann-Liouville convolution integral a la Hadamard finite part. You can choose your method of regularization or analytic continuation as you prefer, but for the positive real domain you end up with the same results for the divided powers, I believe.

Comment: The operator $d^\beta /dx^{\beta}$ in your comment in [http://math.stackexchange.com/a/133194/272980](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/133194/272980) is not Caputo derivative, isn't it? If so, I think that we cannot do calculation $\partial_{t}^{\alpha}t^{-\alpha(k+1)}$ from "my" definition of Caputo derivative. I'm sorry I wasn't able to see through an essential part. Could you explain more details how to consider the above equality?

Comment: The regularization in Eqn. 2.17 in the paper you cite for analytic fcts does appear different from a Hadamard FP regularization, so my initial claims don't seem justified and I'll have to work through the details of the paper myself sometime in the future.

Comment: I see. Thank you for giving thoughtful comments. I'll try to study more, too.